# Prove that $E^{\circ}$ is always open

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $E^{\circ}$ denote the set of all interior points of a set $E$

Prove that $E^{\circ}$ is always open.

Important definitions:

> An **interior point** of a set E, is a point $p$ in which there exists a nbhd $N_{\delta}(p)$ such that $N_{\delta}(p) \subset E$.
>
> A set is said to be **open** if every point of $E$ is an interior point

**My Solution**: I would've just said that the set $E^{\circ}$ is open by this definition.

**But another solution I found was**:

If $x\in E^{\circ} \rightarrow x\in U \subset E^{\circ}$ where $U$ is open.

Therefore any point $x\in U$ has a nbhd $N_{\delta}(p) \subset E$.

This implies $E^{\circ} = \bigcup _{U \subset E}U$.

And from this it is concluded that $E^{\circ}$ is open.

My question is why is this extended argument necessary? This happens to me often where I encounter a question which appears to be asking something simple, but the actual proof is more complicated than initially anticipated.

Comment: What is your technical definition of an open set?

Comment: Interiors are defined in *topological* spaces, not just metric spaces.